# How To Specify Which Module to add Controller to in NestJS CLI?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Ive been playing with NestJS for about a week. So far, Im really liking it. The Module system is great. And, I love how easy it is to do things like parse requests.

One question I do have is with regards to the NestJS CLI.

Suppose I have multiple modules. I can create a controller with the following command.

```
nest g controller Accounts
```

How do I specify which module this controller belongs to?

The CLI seems to default to the last module you created.

How do I change this behavior?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The CLI, to my knowledge, will see if you have any modules that match the name of the controller you are creating. For example, if you run

```sh
nest g mo accounts
nest g mo contacts
nest g mo leads
```

And then you run the same for controllers, but in a different order, like

```sh
nest g co leads
nest g co accounts
nest g co contacts
```

You'll still get the `AccountsController` in the `AccountsModule`, the `LeadsController` in the `LeadsModule`, and the `ContactsController` in the `ContactsModule`

If you are looking to add a specific controller to a module that is named differently than the Controller (i.e. add the `LeadsController` to the `AccountsModule`) you can pass a `path` option as the final parameter to the CLI e.g.

```sh
nest g co leads accounts
```

The path you give is relative to `src` (or whatever your root directory is in the `nest-cli.json`). This will create the directory `accounts/leads` where the `leads.controller.ts` file will live, and will add the controller to the `AccountsModule`.

The reason that Nest adds the new class to the module of the same name by default is to allow for easy feature module development. The need to not specify the module makes the CLI usage much more friendly to developers (usually), and as a fallback, if a module cannot be found, the CLI adds it to the `AppModule` (or whatever you have the root module called).

Answer (score 8):

If a module already exists, you can simply add its name after the controller/service (or else ..)

```
nest generate controller <controller_name> <module_name> [--flat]
```

"--flat" option, if you don't want a new folder generated for your controller

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've been looking for this for days, so I can create services and controllers without creating directories for them.

Comment: @DiegoCândidodaSilva That's a pleasure

Comment: Thank you, this helps me keep my injectables in subdirectories so that I can use something like `npx nest generate service some-service my-module/services --flat` to have the generated file placed in the correct directory.

Comment: This should be the default option imo

Comment: That what i have been looking for

Answer (score 1):

If module exists already, you may just give module name first then what you generating:

```
nest g  pr PriceLevel PriceLevel
```

Will generate PriceLevel provider inside PriceLevel module